# If two real vectors/signals are orthogonal, then are their associated complex vectors/signals also orthogonal?

Tags: orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Being Z1 and Z2 two complex vectors/signals with N samples; X1 and X2 the correspondent real signals with (2N + 1) samples.

Is it true that if X1 and X2 are orthogonal, then are Z1 and Z2 also orthogonal? If Z1 and Z2 are orthogonal, then are X1 and X2 also orthogonal?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $Z_1=(i,1,0)$ and $Z_2=(1,-i,0)$ for the first case.

Consider $Z_1=(1,-i,0)$ and $Z_2=(1,i,0)$ for the second case.